# Tool for making sketches of interfaces for mobile apps

Tags: android, ios, mobile, graphics

I'm looking for a tool for making sketches of mobile UIs, then pass those drafts to a graphic designer. The designer would do advanced prototypes and the diferent drawables for including them in the application.

The target is to allow the fast remote co-work. Is there any tool (web or desktop) for helping with that task better than a paper a pen and a scanner?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really like this web interface

[www.mybalsamiq.com](http://www.mybalsamiq.com)

Answer (score 1):

Drop box shared folders make coordinating with designers much nicer. Also as far as sketch tools I have been using PowerPoint recently. Is nice because they have many pre built shapes and everything can be exported as many types of images. Both as a whole and individual components.